# slideshow with changing font color on each slide + callback font to set color on scroll

Tags: jquery, callback, scroll, slideshow, opacity

I'm trying to accomplish a couple of things here in a header element. Firstly, I'd like a jquery slideshow set to relative. Secondly, I'll have my png logo and nav links fixed sitting in front of the slideshow. since some of the slides will be dark, and some will be light, I'll need the logo + nav links to change to set colors in unison as the images cycle so they can always be read.

So far, it seems like I could accomplish these 2 tasks with cycling through divs, but since the images will be relative and the logo+nav will be fixed, I'll need the opacity of the fixed divs' background to change it's opacity from 0 - 100 as you scroll down and the slideshow scrolls up and out of view.

And since the colors of the logo+nav will sometimes be one color and sometimes be another depending on what slide is showing, I need to add an additional callback telling the logo+nav to return to black upon scroll no matter what they were when scrolling began.

I have a semi working [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/MNFTT/83/).

This demo shows the slideshow + div opacity on scroll. through they are not playing nice together in the fiddle, they are working fine together on my actual site.

Feel free to tear this apart. Thanks!

Comment: How to accomplish. My fiddle shows that I have handled the slide + opacity change on scroll, but how to alter the logo+nav colors per slide, as well as how to set those colors back to black once the user begins to scroll is where I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want ?
http://jsfiddle.net/MNFTT/89/

CSS:

```
#slideshow{
    
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    
} 

#slideshow ul, #slideshow li{
    
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    
} 

.slideshow_item{
    
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    
} 

.slideshow_item img{
    
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    
} 

div.fademe {
    width: 100%; 
    position: fixed; 
    display: block; 
    height: 150px; 
    background: #ffffff; 
    z-index: 8; 
}

#header-wrapper {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100px; 
    z-index: 9; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header .inner {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 0 25px 0 25px; 
    width: 950px; 
    height: 100px; 
    z-index: 10;
}

#header-logo {
    background:url(http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/4227/xlogo.png);
    width:71px;
    height:51px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 31px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#navbar {
    text-align: justify;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

#navbar a{
    font-family: "ss-bol", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000000;
}

#navbar a:hover{
    font-family: "ss-bol", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #595959;
}


#navbar span {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#page {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
}​
```

HTML

```
<div id="header-wrapper">
<div class="fademe"></div>
            <div id="header">
        <div class="inner">
            <a href="/" title"logo"><div id="header-logo"></div></a>
            <div id="navbar">
              <a href="#">NEW</a>
              <a href="/shop">SHOP</a>
              <a href="/wine">ART</a>
              <a href="/blog">BLOG</a>
              <a href="#">MUSIC</a>
              <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
            <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
            <span></span></div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>


<div id="slideshow"> 
    
    <ul>
        
        <li class="slideshow_item">
            
            <a href="#"><img src="http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/6969/newslide2.jpg" alt="persiannewyear11-hp" /></a> 
            
        </li>
        
        <li class="slideshow_item">
            
            <a href="#"><img src="http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/3193/newslide1.jpg" alt="holi11-hp" /></a> 
            
        </li>
        
    </ul> 
    
</div>
<div id="page">
TEXT FOR SCROLLING
.....
</div>
```

JS:

```
/* slideshow */
$(function(){

var slide_pos = 0;
var slide_len = 0;


    slide_len = $(".slideshow_item").size() - 1;

    $(".slideshow_item:gt(0)").hide();

    slide_int = setInterval(function() {

        slide_cur = $(".slideshow_item:eq(" + slide_pos + ")");
        slide_cur.fadeOut(2000);

        slide_pos = (slide_pos == slide_len ? 0 : (slide_pos + 1));

        slide_cur = $(".slideshow_item:eq(" + slide_pos + ")");
        slide_cur.fadeIn(2000);

    }, 5000);




    var divs = $('.fademe');
    var navbar_a=$('#navbar a');
    var navbar=$('#navbar');
    divs.css('opacity', 0);
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    var imgH=$('.slideshow_item').height();
        var percent = $(document).scrollTop()/imgH;
       divs.css('opacity', percent);
        var bg=Math.round(255-(percent*255));
        bg=bg>0?bg:0;
        var fg=255-(bg/2+128);
       console.log(percent,imgH,fg);
       divs.css('background-color','rgb('+bg+','+bg+','+bg+')');
       navbar_a.css('color','rgb('+fg+','+fg+','+fg+')');
    });
});​
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MNFTT/90/  - trying to get all goals, but here is logic conflict, about when to change foreground color by scroll and when by image content;

Comment: Firstly, you're a genius. 

Secondly, this is 99% where I need it to be. The functionality is perfect, but I'll need to change some of the colors (ie. colors of the nav links and div box they are sitting on). Looking at the css, it appears that they don't follow those rules, but are driven purely by the JS. It almost appears that there's 2 sets on top of each other. how can I adjust the colors, as well as incorporate a white version of the logo for when the nav links are white?

thanks a million

Comment: for switching logo version - i think you should place both white and black logo on top of each other and switch them by balancing opacity of the elements, for colors, yes - they controlled by js, you should change rgb things to control them, i usef fg and bg variables in al r g and b, you have to invent how you want to make transitions between colors

Comment: Perfection! I'm basically using the slideshow to cycle divs. Each slide contains an image, as well as a z-index div which holds all header elements in the corresponding colors needed. I'm using the fade in div you made as is, which gives the appearance that whatever color the logo+nav are at the time of scroll, they are turning black. This ensures that all elements are fading in unison and lets me add or subtract slides with specific header colors easily. Thanks again!

Here's the final [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jg5Pg/161/)