# Changing an fixed element's class depending on what section of the page is currently visible (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll-position

Hello fellow developers!

I've had a big scan of the web, including StackOverflow and cannot seem to find anything documenting what I want, nor anything remotely similar to what I want.

I'm building a site with a fixed navbar, however the navbar doesn't actually have a background color (transparent). Within the navbar there are two elements that are visible;

- Client's logo; I have created this using a custom font so I am actually able to control all formatting with css and classes applied via JS.
- Menu toggle button; This is also all element based and I have full control with css and classes applied via JS.

The page structure is `<section>` based, and each section is either an "off-white" or "black".

For example `<section class="dark">...</section>` will have a black background (dur).

---

#### The issue

The menu button and client logo are also black, so I need a way of tracking what the current visible/scrolled section's class is ("dark" or "light") and then apply a class to the navigation via JS.

So if the current section has the class of "light" then the menu button and logo are black, if the current section has the class of "dark" then the menu button and logo change to  white.

---

I am completely aware of the plugins available such as "scrollorama" that have the section spying capabilities but I really only need to utilise a tiny part of the functionality so it's going to be more efficient to just write a custom function. Also open to suggestion.

Comment: I usually wait till the windowload event fires, inspect the top location and height of each section, then on scroll decide based on scroll position and those previously mentioned locations/heights what class to add.

Comment: How do you handle it if you're halfway between two sections? for example, half the menu bar is in a light section and half is in a dark? you might need to re-think this, as i think that would look a little broken.

Comment: @KevinB do you have an example that I can take a look at?

Comment: @kevinB The navbar is extremely small so it really only matters what section the navbar is in, if you're half way between a dark section and a light section the nav will still be on the dark section until you scroll beyond it.

Comment: I have found a site that does a horribly chunky version of this using scrollorama, but it's a similar, less clean concept http://www.theblacksparrow.co.nz/

Comment: Here's an example, keep in mind though that it isn't actually doing what you would need it to do, it just shows how i'm finding the positions of all the sections and then detecting if i'm in them. http://pastebin.com/WGckwwE7 it's modified to fit the page it's working it, but it could be a decent place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for same as you and I found this:

[slideshow with changing font color on each slide + callback font to set color on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792666/slideshow-with-changing-font-color-on-each-slide-callback-font-to-set-color-on)

Hope it can give you some hint!